# ElasticSearch Nest Client cannot be found in .NET Core

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, .net-core

I am migrating from VS 2015 to VS 2017 .NET Core. Project contains Nest library with ElasticClient to contact ElasticSearch. I added Nest (5.4.0) as Nuget package to project and created class that is referencing ElasticSearch class, but ElasticClient doesn't exist (The type or namespace name 'ElasticClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)). Same thing is happening with ConnectionSettings class.

Does Nest library in .NET Core contain ElasticClient class? Should I add another package? Am I doing something wrong? Is there an available .NET Core project that could be used as an example?

Comment: This should work. I've already used Nest (5.4.0) in a .NET Core project. `Nest.ElasticClient` worked happily. Maybe you just didn't restore packages properly yet?
Here is my csproj: https://github.com/Dynatrace/superdump/blob/elasticsearch-support/src/SuperDumpService/SuperDumpService.csproj
Here is my code: https://github.com/Dynatrace/superdump/blob/elasticsearch-support/src/SuperDumpService/Services/ElasticSearchService.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working in VS 2017 with .NET Core 1.1 project. When I downloaded VS 2017 preview 2 in .NET Core 2 it is working correctly.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017  Update 2 was released a while ago. It's no longer in Preview. Update 3 is in preview

Comment: Yes. I installed Update 3.